# error C2664: 'LoadLibraryA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WCHAR *' to 'LPCSTR'

Tags: unicode

I have made all the necessary settings to get my code running. in all configurations i have made the settings as written below:
Configuration type: .dll
USe of MFC: shared dll
character set: multi-byte character set

Please help me to run my code. and help me to understand where am i going wrong.

with regards,
Chini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> character set: multi-byte character set

That means `UNICODE` is not defined, and so a call to the `TCHAR`-based `LoadLibrary()` will map to `LoadLibraryA()` rather than `LoadLibraryW()` (and all other `TCHAR`-based APIs will also map to their Ansi versions instead of their Unicode versions).

You did not show your code, but you are clearly passing a `WCHAR*` value to `LoadLibrary()`.  That will only work if `LoadLibrary()` maps to `LoadLibraryW()` (`character set` is **Unicode**), as `LoadLibraryA()` expects a `CHAR*` (`LPCSTR` is an alias for that).  You cannot pass a `WCHAR*` where a `CHAR*` is expected, and vice versa.

If you are passing a string literal to `LoadLibrary()`, you need to wrap it with the `TEXT()` macro so the literal will respect your `character set` configuration, eg:

```
... = LoadLibrary(TEXT("literal"));
```

Or stop using `TCHAR`-based APIs and call the desired Ansi/Unicode version directly:

```
... = LoadLibraryA("literal");
```

```
... = LoadLibraryW(L"literal");
```

If you are passing a variable instead of a literal, you will have to call `LoadLibraryA()`/`LoadLibraryW()` directly, based on the data type of your variable:

```
... = LoadLibraryA(AnsiVariable);
```

```
... = LoadLibraryW(WideVariable);
```